# How to replace a localhost with meaning full URL name in pom file

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-tomcat-plugin

My application is running on my localhost on URL i.e `http://localhost:8080/WebIntegrationApp`.
Is there any way to replace `http://localhost:8080/WebIntegrationApp` url with `http://WebIntegrationApp` in *pom.xml* file.
I mean I want to run this application using url `http://WebIntegrationApp`.

The OS used is windows7 and here is the plugin used for running tomcat for localhost:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>localhost</server>
        <path>/WebIntegrationApp</path>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>s3cret</password>

    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>tomcat-run</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>run-war-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>tomcat-shutdown</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use any text editor to edit pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run you app on your local machine,you should edit your hosts file. And then edit your pom.xml

On windows systems hosts located: Windows\System32\drivers\etc\
On linux: /etc/hosts

Comment: Thanks for answering. I guess this is not a good idea.If this file has to be used by different users then each one has to edit host files. So i'm looking for  a generic solution.One change works for others.

Comment: Then you should configure your DNS server settings.

Answer (score 0):

This have nothing to do with maven, the `maven-tomcat-plugin` is only responsible of running the configured web application.

It will use the provided server (*localhost*) appended to the port (default is *8080*) and follwed by the webapp context name; yours is ***WebIntegrationApp***.

What you are trying to achieve can be done using a front end server such as [Apache Httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/) by configuring some routing rules so when you hit *`http://localhost:8080/WebIntegrationApp`* in your browser you will be redirected to *`http://WebIntegrationApp`*.
And behind the scenes, there will be a reversing mechanism so when you hit *`http://WebIntegrationApp`*; in background the request is sent to *`http://localhost:8080/WebIntegrationApp`*.

This would need some configuration, if you are not acclimated with Apache Httpd Server. Here is the VirtualHost config you should have to shorten the line:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName      Enter your server DNS name here
  ProxyRequests   Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass  "/" http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse "/" http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```